# Finding a "typical" path

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, np-hardness, polynomial-time

Consider an undirected graph with two distinguished nodes $u\neq v$. How hard is it to find an $u-v$ path, such that its length is as close to the average $u-v$ path length as possible?

Formally, for a path $P$ let $\ell(P)$ denote its length (number of edges on $P$, but a weighted version may also be considered). Let $A$ denote the average length of simple $u-v$ paths:
$$A= \frac{1}{N}\sum \ell(P)$$
where $N$ is the number of simple $u-v$ paths and the summation is taken over all such paths.
Let us call a simple $u-v$ path $P_0$ *typical* if $|\ell(P_0)-A|$ is minimum.

**Question:** What is the complexity of finding such a typical path? Is anything known about this problem?

Comment: Does anybody know the complexity of *sampling* a simple $u$-$v$ path uniformly at random?  That could be useful for approximating the unweighted case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma 1.** *The weighted problem is NP-hard by reduction from Partition.*

**Lemma 2.** *The unweighted problem is NP-hard by reduction from Hamiltonian Path.*

*Proof of Lemma 1.* Given a Partition instance $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, construct the multigraph $G=(V,E)$ with $V=[n+1]$ and, for each $i\in [n]$, two copies of edge $(i, i+1)$, one with weight $x_i$ and the other with weight zero.  Then ask for the path from $1$ to $n+1$ whose weight is as close to average over paths from $1$ to $n+1$.

By linearity of expectation, the average weight is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i/2$, so there is a path with average weight if and only if the Partition instance is feasible.

(If desired, the multigraph can easily be converted to an equivalent graph by splitting each edge $(i, i+1)$ of weight zero into two zero-weight edges.) $~~~\Box$

*Proof sketch for Lemma 2.*  Given a Hamiltonian Path instance $G=(V,E)$ with source $s$ and sink $t$, construct the following multigraph $G'$.  Let $n=|V|$.

First, add a new, long "super-path" from $s$ to $t$ as follows.  Fix some $p, q, k, \ell$ to be determined later. Add $k$ new vertices $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$, with $p$ new multi-edges $(a_i, a_{i+1})$ between each consecutive pair.  Add edges $(s, a_1)$ and $(a_k, t)$.  This addition adds $p^k$ paths of length $k$ from $s$ to $t$.

Now add another (separate) super-path to add $q^\ell$ paths of length $\ell$.

Choose $p, q, k, \ell$ so that the number of added paths is much larger than $n!$, so that the added paths determine (up to lower-order terms) the average path length.  Choose $k$ and $\ell$ with $k < n-1 \ll \ell$, so that the average path length is larger than $n$, and closer to $n$ than to $\ell$.  (Details below.)

Then the typical path will be a Hamiltonian path from $s$ to $t$ in the original graph, if there is one.

Here are the details for choosing $p, q, k, \ell$.
Choose $p=n^{30}$, $q=n^2$, $k=n/3$, and $\ell=5n$.
Then the addition adds
$p^k = n^{10n}$ paths of length $k=n/3$,
and
$q^\ell = n^{10n}$ paths of length $\ell= 5n$.
The average length of the added paths is then $(1/3 + 5)n/2 = 8n/3$.
If there is a Hamiltonian $s$-$t$ path in the original graph, its length will be about $5n/3$ shorter than the average.
The longer added paths, of length $5n$, are about $7n/3$ longer than the average, so they are not better.
(Note that there are at most $n! \ll n^{10n}$ paths in the original graph, of length at most $n$, so they affect the average path length in the final graph by only lower-order terms.)

If a multigraph is not allowed, the construction can be adjusted appropriately by splitting each multi-edge as usual, then taking account how this affects $k$ and $\ell$. $~~~\Box$

Comment: This can surely be extended to show hardness of approximating even the unweighted case, by reducing from the longest-path problem (which is hard to approximate) instead of from hamiltonian path.